# Prooving the existence of the linear map usingt he subspaces of the $n$/dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

I'm trying to solve a problem from some test and i would like to receive the help regarding the accuracy of my solution. I hope that the title is good.

Problem:

Let $S$ and $T$ be subspaces of a $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, such that $dim(S) + dim(T) = n$. Show that there is a linear map $A: V \to V$, where $Ker(A) = S$ and $Im(A) = T$.

My solution:

During the solving i used the next two theorems:

T1: If $A$ is linear map from $V_1(F)$ to $V_2(F)$ ($A: V_1(F) \to V_2(F)$), then the kernel, $Ker(A)$, is the subspace of the $V_1(F)$ and the image, $Im(F)$, is the subspace if the $V_2(F)$.

T2: If $A$ is the linear map from the finite-dimensional vector space $V_1(F)$ to the finite-dimensional vector space $V_2(F)$, than:
$$ dim(Ker(A)) + dim(Im(A)) = dim(V_1).$$

Beacuase $S$ and $T$ are subspaces, than, based on the T1, there exist two linear maps, $A1$ and $A2$, such that $Ker(A1) = S$ and $Im(A2) = T$.

Based on the T2, now we have:
$$ dim(Ker(A1)) + dim(Im(A1)) = dim(V) \iff dim(S) + dim(Im(A1)) = dim(S) + dim(T) \iff \underline{dim(Im(A1)) = dim(T)} \Rightarrow \underline{dim(Im(A1)) = dim(Im(A2))} \Rightarrow \underline{Im(A1) = Im(A2) \,(*)} $$
$$ dim(Ker(A2)) + dim(Im(A2)) = dim(V) \iff dim(Ker(A2)) + dim(T) = dim(S) + dim(T) \iff \underline{dim(Ker(A2)) = dim(S)} \Rightarrow \underline{dim(Ker(A2)) = dim(Ker(A1))} \Rightarrow \underline{Ker(A2) = Ker(A1) \,(**)} $$ 
$$ ((*) \land (**)) \Rightarrow A1 = A2$$

So, i concluded that there is a linear map that satisfies the conditions of the problem.

The question about this is that i'm not sure can i use the theorems in that way? They presume the exictence of the linear map, but the problem gives only the existence of the subpaces of the vector space.

Please, could you tell me is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes! I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way for me:

Since $\dim S+\dim T=n$

Assume $\dim S=m;\dim T=n-m$

Let $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots \alpha_m\}$ be a basis of $S$. Extend it to form a basis of $V$ such that $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots \alpha_m,\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots ,\beta _{n-m}\}$ forms a basis of $V$.

Define $T(\alpha_i)=0$ and $T(\beta_i)=\beta_{i+1}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Why $T(\beta_i) = \beta_{i + 1}$? Which vector will become $\beta_1$?

Comment: $T(\beta_1)=\beta_2,T(\beta_2)=\beta_3$ and so on.Make $T(\beta_{n-m})=\alpha_1$

Comment: Oh! I didn't ask a good question. I wonder for which $x \in V$, $T(x) = \beta_1$? You showed me how for every vector $v$ from $\mathcal{L} = \left\{ \beta_2, \beta_3, ..., \beta_{n - m} \right\}$, there is an $x \in V$, such that $A(x) = t$.